# Access root owned certificate files (Let's Encrypt) from java app running as service

Tags: java, linux, websocket, permissions

I am experimenting with a java service using vertx and websockets to create a chat server.

Everything works fine except secure connections on the live machine.

I have the certificate files from Let's Encrypt configured in a resource file, so far so good.

```
  "certificate": {
    "chain": "/home/letsencrypt/cert/live/x/chain.pem",
    "privkey": "/home/letsencrypt/cert/live/x/privkey.pem",
    "cert": "/home/letsencrypt/cert/live/x/cert.pem"
  }
```

My problem is they all belong to root as it seems to be normal for Let's Encrypt. My java app is registered as a service and starts but I get an access denied error when I try to load the files.

So what would be the best practice or solution to solve that? Copying them to another location and lowering the access rights might not the best solution.

I haven't tried anything else so far.

Comment: *my problem is they all belong to root as it seems to be normal for lets encrypt.* Well they should belong to whomever is running the process to which the certs belong. And that should *not* be root for security reasons. If Apache, that would often be www-data on Debian systems

Comment: they are used by multiple application, for example also by apache and it seems that apache is reading them as root during startup

Comment: AFAIK Apache starts under root then continues as another user (www-data on Debian). In theory it's only the private key file you should have to worry about. I'm not sure it needs to be owned by root but you could give it a group read permission